# Report viewer Not able to Load Initial Values on Form Load When using Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, database, reportviewer

i having i have reportviewer in my software and i have filter but since i using filter i am not able to load the full data table without no filters to formload it's asking for overload.

here is code i have write now

```
 private void StockInsReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pURCHASE_TABLETableAdapter.Fill(this.stockInsDataSet.PURCHASE_TABLE);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

private void filterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
              this.pURCHASE_TABLETableAdapter.Fill(this.stockInsDataSet.PURCHASE_TABLE,filterComboBox.Text);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

when try to build i am getting this error

```
  Error 1   No overload for method 'Fill' takes 1 arguments
```

is there anyways i can load the full datatable with any filters on form load and when the button is pressed then apply the filters ?

Answer (score 0):

adapter.Fill(yourDataSet, "YourTableName")
That is the fix for your error

Comment: thanks for help it didn't help i am getting Error 1 The best overloaded method match for error mate it stills as for extra filter overload